# kendo datasource does not work with breezeJs

Tags: kendo-ui, breeze

I try to get data from a server with kendo.data.breeze.Source in my datacontext.js file, using this code :

```
function getClients() {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Clients");
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.breeze.Source({
        manager: new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName),
        query: query,
        serverSorting: true,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        pageSize: 100,            
    });        
    return  dataSource ; 
}
```

But when I try to log the results using `console.log(datacontext.getClients());`, datasource is empty.

Comment: I tried to use the kendo breeze data source and i continually ran into issues.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically only creating a datasource here, not fetching data from the specified endpoint. In this case, you could call [fetch method](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-fetch) of kendo datasource. Also read about [read method](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-read)

```
dataSource.fetch(function(){
   var data = this.data()
   console.log(data.length)  
})
```

However, the point of using kendo-breeze is to create a datasource that supports breeze queries and their result sets to be used in any kendo widget that uses it. For example, kendo grid.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
   dataSource: yourKendoBreezeDataSource,
   dataBound: function (e) {
     console.log(e)
   },
   height: 550
})
```